# Generating XML Files & Returning Zipped In A Folder Within Docker

Tags: c#, api, docker, asp.net-core, memorystream

I am currently creating an API (asp.net core 2.2) which takes in a json input, generates XML files based on the json, adds them to a folder structure and then returns this folder structure zipped as a response. I am currently struggling to imagine how I am going to store the file once generated within Docker and then how to add them to a zip file in a specific folder format to return to the requester.

I created a similar app (without using APIs) in Winforms, meaning I could just add folders and files to a temporary file on the clients machine and then zip it up all locally, but I'm wondering whether this is possible on Docker too (or if there is a better way all together?). Once the zip file has been returned to the requester there is no requirement to keep it stored anywhere either.

I have done some research into using file/memory streams but not come across anything particularly useful.

Any resources or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can still use the file system to temporarily store files. Using docker just means that the files will be lost if you had to rebuild the container.

Comment: Is this a good practice though, as it seems a bit too basic? Also, can I just create a temporary file on the C drive say (e.g. 'C:\Temp')?

Comment: Yeah. What's wrong with basic? You don't have to do something extravagant just because Docker. I think its more common to put files under ~/App_Data/, but you can put them anywhere.

Comment: Since you do not want to store it in docker, you could create a temp folder by yourself in docker and then after return the zip file, delete the temp folder.

Comment: Thanks both! This is the technique I have decided to implement in this case. Out of interest, would it be possible to use a memorystream to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you want to zip a folder, it is impossible, you could create file stream in memory, but it is impossible to create folder with files in memory.